# How does one multiply by a constant in a VS1.1 assembly vertex shader?

Tags: shaders

I'd like to multiply a vector by -1

e.g.

```
mul    r0,    r0,    -1
```

When I try this, I get this error message:

```
SimpleShaderA.vsh(20,17): error X2000: syntax error : unexpected integer '1l'
```

How can I specify -1 in my (first) shader program?

Comment: Why are you writing assembly shaders? Modern shader models (4+) do not allow you to do this, and unless you have a very compelling need to achieve a clever effect on a very low-end card you'll probably learn more writing in HLSL.

Comment: i've been set an assignment that uses assembly shaders to teach us the math more than anything else ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `mul` assembly instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147227%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) takes registers as inputs, not constants. You can do this instead

```
def c0, -1, -1, -1, -1
mul r0, r0, c0
```

which uses the [def instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to define a constant vector in register `c0` and uses that as the second multiplicand to `mul`.

You could also use [swizzling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the `c0` register, so you could put different constants you may need to multiply by in `c0`'s components. You can also just write the multiplication in terms of `c0` and assign it values via the `Set***ShaderConstant*` APIs.